# Making full screen section that can grow with content

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to make section that takes up the full screen, but that can also grow further when the content requires it

I am using the `min-height` property but it does not seems to work: it is indeed taking the full height space, but it won't grow even if the content overflows. Unfortunately I won't be able to use flexbox for this since the size need to be set for each element (So I can't rely on it to center my element I think).

html:

```html
<section id="MusicStyle">
    <div class="parchment parchment-style">
        <h1>Music style</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Style 1</li>
            <li>Style 2</li>
            <li>Style 3</li>
            <li>Style 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="parchment parchment-hardware">
        <h1>Hardware</h1>
        <p>I am using the Hercules something pro </p>
        <p>I need a jack audio input to connect to your sound system. Tests can be done for free to check if I can work with your setup.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="parchment parchment-pictures">
        <h1>Previous parties</h1>
        <div class="parties">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508854806753-7878ec6a6632?w=500&q=90" width="500"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543320777-d4102f7e1aa3?w=500&q=90" width="500"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524368535928-5b5e00ddc76b?w=500&q=90" width="500"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533174072545-7a4b6ad7a6c3?w=500&q=90" width="500"/>
        </div>
    </div> 
</section>
```

Scss:

```
#MusicStyle {
    min-height           : auto !important;
    background           : black;
    text-align           : center;

    .parchment {
        display: block;
        width: 25%;
        margin: 2em auto 2em auto;
        padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
        /** Setting bg and color stuff **/
    }

    /**
     * Doing the responsiveness by hands bother me since it was pretty auto with flexbox
     **/
    .parchment-style {
        width: 383px !important;

        @media (max-width: 1500px) {
            width: 25% !important;
        }

        @media (max-width: 1200px) {
            width: 30% !important;
        }

        @media (max-width: 900px) {
            width: 40% !important;
        }

        @media (max-width: 550px) {
            width: 60% !important;
        }
    }

    .parchment-hardware {
        width: 383px !important;

        p {
            margin-top: 1em;
            &:first-of-type {
                margin-top: 0;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 1500px) {
            width: 35% !important;
        }

        @media (max-width: 830px) {
            width: 40% !important;
        }

        @media (max-width: 650px) {
            width: 65% !important;
        }
    }

    .parchment-pictures {
        width: 50% !important;

        @media (max-width: 1200px){
            width: 70% !important;           
        }

        @media (max-width: 830px){
            width: 90% !important;           
        }

        .prestations {
            margin-bottom: 2em;
        }
    }

    div {
        h1 {
            font-size: 4em;
        }

        ul {
            padding   : 0;
            margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
            list-style: none;

            li  {
                padding: 0;
                margin : 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `parties` div is a slideshow made with the Slick library so no need to have all pictures shown at once.

This code seems to work-ish on Firefox, but on Chrome the picture slideshow overflows on my next section and the current one still takes one view height. I haven't even tries with IE/Edge yet...

To mention that, this code is really ugly and I'd like to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try width and height set to AUTO, alongside your min-height and min-width?